# does string end character corrupt memory? buffer[size]='\0';

Tags: c++

```
char * buffer = new char[SIZE];
memcpy(buffer , somedata , SIZE);

buffer[SIZE]='\0';
```

Does the last line corrupt memory?
`buffer` is SIZE length, and we are putting some data out of this range.
Can anyone explain it for me please?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's undefined behavior. You're writing beyond the legal range.

Arrays are 0-based in C++, which means indexes 0 to SIZE-1 are valid.

Comment: so how do u set the end char?

Comment: @alirakiyan `buffer[SIZE-1] = '\0'`?

Comment: @alirakiyan no, you don't. Do you want your buffer to hold `SIZE` characters? If so, allocate SIZE+1 and set the one at SIZE to 0.

Comment: There is no end char, you are confusing strings with memory buffers, memcpy does not handle strings but memory buffers. Well, memory buffers can contain strings, but they are not the same thing. Is SOMEDATA also of size SIZE? It is "illegal" to read out of range as well namely.

Comment: everything is memory. strings are too. test it .

Comment: @AndersLindén: Erm, what is the result of `new char[n]` if not a pointer to a memory buffer?

Comment: It will be a pointer to a memory buffer. What I wanted to say is that memcpy handles memory and that there is no need to put a string terminator in the end of a memory buffer that you have copied data into.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the last line corrupt memory?

Yes.

> buffer is SIZE length, and we are putting some data out of this range.

Correct.

> Can anyone explain it for me please?

buffer is SIZE length, and we are putting some data out of this range.

Comment: Thank you @juanchopanza. Most of the work was already done for me.

Comment: Well, I'm sure the same words in a slightly different format make the answer abundantly clear.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I was considering EBCDIC.

Answer (score 1):

Create a buffer of size SIZE+1 if you want room for the '\0' character at SIZE index.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it corrupts the memory. The array size must be one bigger than the data if the data is not zero terminated and you want to append a 0 yourself. Also the index is zero based, so to set buffer[SIZE] the number of chars must be SIZE+1.

```
char* buffer = new char[SIZE+1];
//                          ^^ 
memcpy( buffer, somedata, SIZE );
buffer[SIZE]='\0';
```

Comment: @Thomas: Please post your _full_ answer when it is complete, rather than intermediate stages. SO is not a race.